# Sonarqube CSS analysis is failing after detecting the nodejs version

Tags: java, css, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I have a Jenkins job which is analyzing the java, css, heml and js code with the help of sonarscanner.
I am successfully able to analyze the java code but when it comes to UI code the Soanrqube is failing with the below error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

```
05:28:00.442 INFO: Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=45894ms
05:28:00.442 INFO: Java Test Files AST scan
05:28:00.445 INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
05:28:00.448 INFO: Java Test Files AST scan (done) | time=6ms
05:28:00.448 INFO: Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java] (done) | time=56448ms
05:28:00.448 INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Metrics [cssfamily]
05:28:00.489 WARN: Metric 'comment_lines_data' is deprecated. Provided value is ignored.
05:28:00.758 INFO: 0/0 source files have been analyzed
05:28:04.585 INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Metrics [cssfamily] (done) | time=4137ms
05:28:04.585 INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Rules [cssfamily]
05:28:04.585 DEBUG: Checking node version
05:28:04.671 DEBUG: Using Node.js v6.10.3
05:28:04.673 DEBUG: Deploying bundle to X:\AEMBD\PBCOM_BUILD\.scannerwork
05:32:15.661 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
05:32:15.661 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
05:32:15.661 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
05:32:15.661 INFO: Total time: 5:30.750s
05:32:15.825 INFO: Final Memory: 40M/1608M
05:32:15.825 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
05:32:15.826 ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sonar.css.plugin.CssRuleSensor.saveIssues(CssRuleSensor.java:165)
    at org.sonar.css.plugin.CssRuleSensor.execute(CssRuleSensor.java:97)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:45)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:62)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:74)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:166)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:300)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:295)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:269)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:82)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:131)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
05:32:15.827 ERROR: 
05:32:15.828 ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeeded?
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
```

You can see in the above snippet that it is able to detect the node version then while deploying the bundle it is failing, not sure about the cause if the issue.

Comment: It looks as sonarscanner bug. Additionaly, read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12292000

Comment: It is saying 0 source files has been analysed. Could you please share the sonar.properties that you are using to analyse the UI code.